# Twitter urls and # selector

Tags: twitter

I implementing my own Twitter button in my page. The url I'm passing is the url of the page + a selector "#" to scroll the page at the exact location.

Everything works perfectly if I pass the url of the page. But if I add for example "#idName" at the end of the url twitter forward me to the user "idName".

So in other words, Twitter thinks #idName is referring to its user and not a specific html element in my page.

How to solve this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing "#", I pass the code "%23"